# WiFi Hotspot Security / Payments

Tags: networking, heroku, wifi, router, modem

I'm setting up a local coffee shop network-And we need to display a terms of service / authentication screen before they can connect to internet.

Internet --> PC/SERVER --> Wireless Router

Then install software on the PC bridge to run the prompt? If not authenticated display this HTML page?

Comment: What's your programming question?

Comment: I'm fairly sure these disclaimers don't actually change any of the legalities involved. Why are you displaying the message and what are you hoping to get out of it ? You can do it like tombull suggested, but my guess would be that its not worth the screen space it's printed on.

Answer (score 1):

You could run "Captive Portal" software on the computer, or better, on the wireless router itself. If you find a router that supports the DD-WRT firmware, or alternatively have m0n0wall on the PC they both include captive portal sofware which can provide a screen that users have to log into before using the internet. I haven't looked fully into the m0n0wall one but I know you can customise the login page, so I would expect you can customise the error page as well.